# Ionic 3- Possible to trigger an IonChange event from component?

Tags: angular, ionic3

In short, I'm working on an app with many forms. In most of them, it is expected that if the user return from the usual Confirmation view where they see the data they put it (in case they want to omdify it) back to the Form, the form should retain that data.

I am using reactive forms for this, and for the most case, it works.
On component initialization, I check if the Form received some info via an EventEmitter that fires from the Confirmation component:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    if (this.cardData) {
      this.retrievedFormData = {
    amount: this.cardData.card.amount.amount,
    card: {
      number: this.cardData.card.number,
      trade: this.cardData.card.trade,
      type: this.cardData.card.type,
      cardId: this.cardData.cardId,
    },
    }
    this.initForm();
  }
```

initForm() initializes the reactive form, and every parameter checks whether the component received previous data that got stored as the retrievedFormData object. Example:

```
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      amount: [(this.retrievedFormData ? this.retrievedFormData.amount : null),
        [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.01), Validators.pattern(amountRegex)]],
})
```

This way the parameters can easily 'autofill' themselves if the Form received data.

There is just one item in the entire app that is not autofilling well. I have an ion-select that contains the usual *ngFor of options. Each option is an object containint 4 parameters.

html:

```
  <ion-select name="card" formControlName="card" okText="{{ 'COMMON.OK' | translate }}" cancelText="{{ 'COMMON.CANCEL' | translate }}"(ionChange)="handleCardSelection($event)" >
    <ion-option *ngFor="let card of cards" [value]="card">{{card.number}} - {{card.type}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

'card' was initialized as an AbstractControl, and the object has 4 parameters, of which the user sees two in the dropdown, the card's number and the type (credit/debit). All of the parameters, tho, are stored via the **ionChange** located in the ion-select, which calls upon a method in the component called **handleCardSelection()** that stores the value of the object's parameters:

```
  handleCardSelection(card) {
        this.chosenCardData = {
          cardId: card.id,
          type: card.type,
          trade: card.trade,
          number: card.number
        };
    }
```

Everything works well and dandy when it's timer to submit the data and send it onto the Confirmation view. When I try to return, however, my ion-select is not preloading the information that it has received (and I have tested several times that the Form does, indeed, get all of its information back, so the card object does appear).

Like in the example above with the card amount, I am trying to make the component check if it has received a 'card' object:

```
  card: [(this.retrievedFormData ? this.retrievedFormData.card : null),
      Validators.required],
```

And below, reflecting the formControlName that I assigned to the ion-select:

```
this.cardFC = this.formGroup.get('card');
```

But no matter what I try, the ion-select will **not** auto-select the option that matches the info it has received.

So after all this, my question would be the following:

(ionChange) seems to be the event that sets the option itself.

```
<ion-select name="card" formControlName="card" (ionChange)="handleCardSelection($event)">
```

Since that (ionChange) seems to be triggered only by a manual input, and I'd like to activate it automatically if the component detects that it has received info... Is there a way to trigger that ionChange from the compont itself? That way, during the same ngOnInit that checks for previous info and stores it, I could fire the event to pre-select the card that matches the received data.

Edit: Since Suraj mentioned it (and it wasn't a bad approach), I did try to call `handleCardSelection()` from the ngOnInit, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: Why not just call `handleCardSelection(retrievedFormData.card)` in `if(cardaData)`?

Comment: I tried @SurajRao, but the ion-select never autofilled. Shame because it was a very intuitive possible solution

Comment: How are you setting `cards` options?  If cards is received asynchronously, its possible the list is not filled when you set the selection

Comment: It's essentially an array that initialises as empty, and the constructor calls a method like getCardsList() that retreives a block of data, with each object being a specific card with those parameters. Then, that data block gets stored in the array, allowing me to perform a "let card of cards"

Comment: so its empty when reactive form sets the selection? is it empty at the time? You may need to initialize the form _after_ the ion select option list is fetched

Comment: No, sorry. I didnt explain myself well enough. The order of initialization of this component is:
- 1: retrieve the list of cards, store them in the array.
- (via ngOnInit) 2: check if the form received data to preload.
- 3: launch initForm to initialize the form, whether it had previous data or not (fields without data initialize empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to `ionChange` and triggering it.

The `ion-select` sets the preselected card from the list of options. It seems to check the *reference*. The `retrievedFormData.card` is a different object from the list of cards.

You will have to get the reference from the option like so:

```
let selectedCard = this.cards.find((c)=>c.id==this.retrievedFormData.card.id);
```

And then set in initform:

```
card: [(selectedCard ? selectedCard : null),
  Validators.required],
```